# jQuery - preserve html elements after change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails to implement a simple edit/submit button to replace the content of h4 that has class named "special-content".

Here is my code for rhtml:

```
    <div class="modal-body" style="height: 280px !important;">
      <%= image_tag("special/turkey.png", :alt => "turkey", :class => "special-img") %><br>
      <h4 class="special-content">#93 Turkey, Avocado & Cheese</h4><h4>&nbsp;with Small     Sized Drink & Chip</h4>
    </div>
```

and here is my code for jQuery, which is implemented right above the rhtml code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", "#edit", function() {
    $('#edit').replaceWith('<a class="btn" id="submit">Submit</a>');
    $('.special-content').replaceWith('<input class="special-content-edit" type="text" value="' + $('.special-content').html() + '">');
    $('.special-img').replaceWith('<input class="special-img-edit" type="text" value="' +     $('.special-img').attr('src') + '">');
  });

  $("body").on("click", "#submit", function() {
    $('#submit').replaceWith('<a class="btn" id="edit">Edit</a>');
    $('.special-img-edit').replaceWith('<img class="special-img" src="' + $('.special-img-    edit').val() + '">');
    $('.special-content-edit').replaceWith('<h4 class="special-content">' + $('.special-content-edit').val() + '</h4>');
  });
});
</script>
```

The jQuery should allow users to replace the h4 content. Everything works fine. However, if I navigate to another link and come back to the page, the h4 content changes back to the original content ("#93 Turkey, Avocado & Cheese"). How can I preserve the changed element?

Comment: Cookies, local storage or serverside are the options for persistent storage.

Comment: When the user clicks on 'Submit' button, make an AJAX call to the server and send the updated text, so that it is saved in the database.

Comment: That's quite a problem. As far as I know, when a browser loads a page, it makes some kind of cache over it, so if you make changes to that page via javascript, navigate to another link and then hit the back button in your browser, it'll show the previous page, which was cached as it was first rendered. Notice also, if you can debug your app, that when you hit the back button, your action (the one that renders the page) doesn't get hit.

Comment: Could you provide a tutorial for making an AJAX call to the server and send the updated text?